# full screen crashes on Mac using Opencv

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

So I have searched the whole of internet and found nothing interesting that could solve my problem. However, I found this link who claimed to have patch in there. I have no idea how to configure that patch on my system, the link is: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2846

The issue is much similar with some following parts of code:

```
namedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
moveWindow("Original",0,0);
setWindowProperty("Original", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
imshow("Original",frame);
```

Error code is same as in the link with NSFullScreenWindow sliders.

I need a full screen so that I could locate all the toolbar objects as well as the bottom bar on Mac for my image processing project.

Please if there's any workaround do let me know!

Thanks :)